# CSS Menu: Fill Total Area Equally, Vertically-Centered text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple CSS menu.  Here are the constraints:

1. Fill 100% of the width of the parent container
2. The parent container has a percentage-based width
3. Have each button be equal-width
4. Have the entire button be clickable (i.e. the anchor tag expands to fill the entire li tag)
5. Have button width dynamically generated.
6. have the text vertically aligned in the center of the menu
7. We can safely assume there are only 3 menu items.  (it would be nice to have it work for N items, but not necessary).

Here is the html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Here are my attempts, each has its own failing.

1. http://jsfiddle.net/QzYAr/266/ (widths aren't expressed as a %)

   ```
   ul {
       width: 600px;
       display: table;
       table-layout: fixed; 
       background: #EEE;
   }

   li {
       float: left;
       border: 1px dotted red;
   }

   a {
       display: table-cell;
       height: 50px;
       vertical-align: middle;
       text-align: center;
       width: 150px;
       border: 1px dotted green;
   }
   ```
2. http://jsfiddle.net/RzeK2/ (Anchor tag doesn't fill height)

   ```
   ul {
       width: 80%;
       display: table;
       table-layout: fixed; 
       background: #EEE;

   }

   li {
       float: left;
       border: 1px dotted red;
   }

   a {
       display: table-cell;
       height: 50px;
       vertical-align: middle;
       text-align: center;
       width: 150px; /*this is the part that needs work?*/
       border: 1px dotted green;
   }
   ```
3. http://jsfiddle.net/XsLHY/ (Anchor tag text isn't vertically centered)

   ```
   ul {
       width: 80%;
       display: table;
       table-layout: fixed; 
       background: #EEE;

   }

   li {
       display: table-cell;
       width: 33%;
       height: 50px;
       vertical-align: middle;
       text-align: center;
       border: 1px dotted red;
   }

   a {
       display: block;
       border: 1px dotted green;
       height: 50px;
   }
   ```
4. http://jsfiddle.net/w55Lg/ [suggested by two answers below] (Creates ugly button if text wraps, and also other buttons aren't full height now)

   ```
   same as three, plus:
   a {
       line-height: 50px;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ul {
    width: 80%;
    background: #EEE;

}
li {
    width:33.33333333%;
    float:left;
}
a{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
}
a:hover {
    background:red;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/QzYAr/267/

EDIT: If you have longer text, you can wrap it inside a `<span>` tag and add this CSS:

```
ul span{
    display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:14px;
}
```

Comment: Is there any solution other than to set line-height?  This creates a bad state if the text in the button wraps.

Comment: Antonis: Please make that an answer and I will accept it. There is still a theoretical problem with it (if the text is really long, stuff breaks) but that theoretical problem is outside of my use case.  Thank you!

Comment: Joshua, you re welcome, but how longer can be a menu item text?! I think the span solution covers the 99% of the cases!

Answer (score 1):

Using fiddle #2, updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/XsLHY/1/

You just need to add a matching line-height to the `li` as the height of the `a`.

CSS

```
    ul {
        width: 80%;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed; 
        background: #EEE;

    }

    li {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 33%;
        height: 50px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px dotted red;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    a {
        display: block;
        border: 1px dotted green;
        height: 50px;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any solution other than to set line-height?  This creates a bad state if the text in the button wraps.

Comment: If you don't set either the `li` `line-height` or the `a` `height`, it centered also for me in the fiddle.

Comment: DrCord: I believe that is my second example in the question.  If so, that means the anchor tag doesn't fill the li vertically.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using:

```
display: flex;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XsLHY/3/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LD2w4/

To fix the anchor problem, you can switch the order, so the `<a>` wraps the `<li>` instead of the other way around:

```
<ul>
    <a href="#"><li>Item 1</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Item 2</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Item 3</li></a> 
</ul>
```

Comment: That's not really a great idea, nor does it solve anywhere near the entire problem.

Comment: I also can't do this.  The ul is being generated by my CMS (wordpress).

Comment: Why is it a bad idea?